# While Rido possessing another body, will their bite turn the victim into a vampire?

Tags: vampire-knight

Rido can transfer his soul into/possess other people's bodies.

Now, if he bites someone while in that other body, will they turn into a vampire? Or would it be like if any other non-pure blood bit them?

Answer (score 1):

No, they wouldn't because what Rido does is possession where he is controlling another's body, as such he can only do what the other body can do. This is shown with Shizuka Hio when she was possessing the body of her relative Maria Kurenai and was able to use Maria's abilities

> She could also possess the bodies of other vampires like Rido Kuran, resulting in obtaining their powers, such as using Maria's body to see through the eyes of birds.
>
> <sup>[Shizuka Hio > Powers and Abilities](http://vampireknight.wikia.com/wiki/Shizuka_Hio#Powers_and_Abilities)</sup>

Also, while Rido was in Senri's body, Rima was able to attack Senri, indicating that the forced obedience the lesser vampires have to Purebloods does not apply, rather the hesitation to attack Senri at first was because it was still Senri's body that they'd be hurting. If Rido's status as a Pureblood was transferred to Senri and thus allowing him to create Level D's, then this obedience would have been transferred as well.